# integrate Bootstrap4 in laravel5.5 & vuejs2 project

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-4, laravel-5.5

I wish to **benefit from the pure beauty of many bootstrap4 template inside a laravel & vuejs project**. I've a lot of posts about the issue and i'ave attempted to do their propositions, but it's still not working for me. even though it sees the sass folder and accepts those css rules, for javascript files it's not the case. **The core situation to explain that: is my hamburger menu, because when i resize my browser to the size of a smartphone, the hamburger menu does not work well.**

Comment: my resources/assets/js/app.js file

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');
import 'bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/jquery.min.js';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/popper.js';
import Popper from 'popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js';

Comment: I think you just simple add  <script src=".../boostrap.js">, <link="boostrap.css"> in your header of blade file ? Make sure boostrap load  before your bundle.js or customjs file.. I did this way with React, and Vuejs for ejs file. And all it work...

Comment: the thing is that through the use of vuejs i will create my vues, not blade files anymore. cuz if it was only that i just have to import bootstrap through CDN. I'm asking how to integrate bootstrap4 in the vuejs side inside my vues. which configurations should i follow?